# Taking screen shots for an UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, screen-capture

I want take screen shot for particular portion in my view (to be specific an imageview),is there any chance for that....

Comment: Do you want to take a screen shot **of** the image view or **for** the image view. I appreciate your English may not be great, but there is a difference between the two (of and for) and depending on which you mean the answer will be different. For example, if you're trying to take a screenshot **of** the image view, why not just use the image in the image view instead of trying to screenshot it?

Comment: Sorry screenshot of the imageview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need to do `renderInContext`.

```
// Size of the result rendered image
CGSize targetImageSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100);
// Check for retina image rendering option
if (NULL != UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions) UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(targetImageSize, NO, 0);
else UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetImageSize);

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
// The view to be rendered
[[yourImageView layer] renderInContext:context];
// Get the rendered image
UIImage *original_image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Thanks for ur code.I think I'm not specific with my Question I'm using 2 imageviews one on another.I want to take take the screen shot of the two imageviews..

Comment: Yes. Add those two image views on a UIView, and render that view.

Comment: Say the UiImageView is of size 768x1024 and I need to take screenshot of 200x200 rectangle centred at the centre of UIImageView. Do i need to translate CTM first?